# error getting was unix with os.path.getatime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, operating-system, os.path

I want to get the unix era of the file, but I get an error.

Code:

```
import os
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl


# Data do dia em unix.
data_hoje = time()

# Parâmetro de classificação em unix.
quinze_dias = 1296000
trinta_dias = 2592000
tres_meses = float(7776000)
seis_meses = 15552000

# Definição das pastas de trabalho.
main_path = r'C:\Users\eduar\Documents'

book = openpyxl.Workbook()

book.create_sheet('Dados')
frutas_page = book['Dados']
frutas_page.append(['Nome', 'Último acesso', 'Última modificação', 'Tamanho'])

for root, subfolder, filenames in os.walk(main_path):
    for file in filenames:
        unix_arquivo = os.path.getatime(file)
        if data_hoje - unix_arquivo >= tres_meses:
            nome = os.path.basename(file)
            acesso = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(file)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            modificacao = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            frutas_page.append([nome, acesso, modificacao])

book.save('S:/Teste.xlsx')
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\Documentos\ELO\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    unix_arquivo = os.path.getatime(file)
  File "S:\Python\3.9.7\lib\genericpath.py", line 60, in getatime
    return os.stat(filename).st_atime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado: 'adxregistrator.log'
```

The error is happening right at the time of getting the unix era of file access.

Comment: This can happen if the file is deleted while the loop is running.

Comment: I thought that too, but then I changed it to a folder just for consultation and that wouldn't happen changes and the error persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`FileNotFoundError`" is the give-away. That means that the `file` you pass to `getatime` cannot be found. `file` is returned by `os.walk`, so you can be pretty sure it does actually exist, so why can't it be found? Because you need to provide the *path* to the file, and `os.walk` only returns the *filename*.

Try this instead:

```
import os

for root, subfolder, filenames in os.walk("/var/tmp/"):
    for file in filenames:
        unix_arquivo = os.path.getatime(os.path.join(root, file))
        print("file: " + file + ". atime: " + str(unix_arquivo))
```

Note that even still, you may get "FileNotFoundError" for some files. For example, symbolic links may need special handling.

Comment: Thank you very much, really. It worked really well! Right now you are my favorite person in the whole world, extremely grateful to you. A hug from Brazil.